# Linked LIst sorting and Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am currently working on a program which is meant to hold inventory for a watercraft rental company. This program uses a linked list to hold the data about the inventory. I have gotten all of the functions to work other than print by price. This function is meant to sort the linked list in order of lowest to highest price and then print the list. I think that my sorting algorithm is alright but I am getting a seg fault that I can not find the cause of. Any help is appreciated. The following code is my print by price function.

```
  //creates a new list and copies every number from inventory over to this one
  //except add the values in order from lowest to highest by adding in order
  int i = 0;
  //initialize new list
  list_t *sorted = (list_t*)malloc(sizeof(list_t));
  sorted->size = list->size;
  sorted->head = NULL;
  sorted->tail = NULL;
  //make temp variable for iteration
  watercraft_t *init = list->head;
  watercraft_t *temp = list->head;
  watercraft_t *prev = NULL;
  for(i = 0; i < list->size; ++i){
    watercraft_t *new = (watercraft_t*)malloc(sizeof(watercraft_t));
    new  = init;
    if(sorted->head == NULL){
      new = sorted->head;
      new->next = NULL;
    }
    else if(new->total_price < temp->total_price){
      prev->next = new;
      new->next = temp;
    }
    else if(temp->next == NULL){
      temp->next = new;
      new->next = NULL;
    }
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
    init = init->next;
  }
```

This is the structure which is within the linked list holding the data

```
typedef struct watercraft {
    char type[15];     // e.g. pontoon, sport boat, sailboat, fishing,
                       //      canoe, kayak, jetski, etc.
    char make[20];
    char model[30];
    int propulsion;    // 0 = none; 1 = outBoard; 2 = inBoard;
    char engine[15];   // Suzuki, Yamaha, etc.
    int hp;             // horse power
    char color[25];
    int length;        // feet
    double base_price;
    double total_price;
    accessories_t extras;
    struct watercraft *next;
} watercraft_t;

If there is any other code that is necessary for this problem please let me know. There are about 400 more lines of code for this project.
```

Comment: "I think that my sorting algorithm is alright but I am getting a seg fault". This probably means it is not all right. Indeed, it (1) is an O(n) algorithm, which means it cannot possibly sort correctly and (2) allocates a new element at each step and promptly throws allocated memory away, never to be seen again. If you find yourself writing something like `x = malloc(....); x = y;` you should consider putting your project aside and re-reading that chapter on pointers.

Comment: Ahh yeah that would be an issue. I was initially doing this a different way and forgot to delete that statement. Thank you